# How to store a Channel in a Concurrent Dictionary

Tags: c#, system.threading.channels

A rather tricky one here but the concept I'm trying to fathom is fairly simple.

I have a public static concurrent dictionary, accessible from other classes and threads:

```
public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> tcpServerChannelDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
```

I have one particular background thread where I initially create a new C# Channel and store the instance inside the dictionary. Within this same thread (in the same method) I then start to wait for messages asynchronously. Have removed some unnecessary code bloat from the method:

```
var myChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
            tcpServerChannelDictionary.TryAdd(int, myChannel);

await foreach (var data in myChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
{
    // Do something with message
}
```

First stumbling block was I couldn't define the static dictionary with the "object" as a channel i.e. ConcurrentDictionary<int, Channel>... becuase I'd get a warning sign that "Channel: Static Types cannot be used as type arguments" so this is why I declared an object type instead.

This appeared to work without VS code warnings until I then try to access the dictionary object from another class (and what will be another thread):

```
if (TcpServer.tcpServerChannelDictionary.TryGetValue(int, out Channel myChannel))
{
   await myChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(data);
}
```

[image]

I somehow need to either cast the object to the channel I'm trying to acess so i can write a message to it, or some other solution that prevents the warnings. I'm new to channels but saw immediately how powerful using them will be.

Comment: Channel is a helper static class. The method returns a Channel<T> where T=string in this case. You can put those in your dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Channel` class is a helper static class with factory methods on it. All of those methods return a `Channel<T>`. In your case you are creating `Channel<string>` objects, and that's a type that a Dictionary *can* be constructed from.

```
public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Channel<string>> tcpServerChannelDictionary = new();
//... 
if (TcpServer.tcpServerChannelDictionary.TryGetValue(int, out var /*Channel<string>*/ myChannel)) 
{
   await myChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(data);
}
```

Now if for whatever reason you still needed to use the `object` type for the values of your dictionary  (maybe you have different generic parameters for `Channel<T>` and you want them all in the same collection) your `out` variable still needs to be `object` and then you need to cast it:

```
if (TcpServer.tcpServerChannelDictionary.TryGetValue(int, out var /*object*/ oChannel) && oChannel is Channel<string> myChannel)
{
   await myChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(data);
}
```

Comment: Lol that wasn't the most intelligent question I've ever asked now seeing what the issue was, second pair of eyes always helps a tired pair of eyes... thanks bud.